# Help for interpreting residuals vs. fitted plot

Tags: regression

I'm confused and find it tough to see a pattern. Most of the data is scattered on the left side. Can I get help on interpreting this plot?

[image]

Comment: Even when knowing what you are plotting, this particular way of showing will be not very helpful. Maybe you could use a 3D plot or a colour coding for the number of entries. And double-logarithmic plots do not help much for understanding, either. In principle it tells you that most fitted values are "small", while your residuals might show higher variance. What the numbers or the red line in the plot are mean -- no clue.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is only one independent variable and it has only a linear relationship in your model, the fitted values on the x axis have to be similar in shape to bsqft. So, you have a lot of cases where bsqft is relatively low and then you have a long right tail. I would check the normality of the residuals.

Although the loess line (the red line in your plot) does not show any strong pattern, there does seem to be a pattern among the poorly fitted points: The worst fitting points at the low end have high positive residuals, those at the high end have high negative residuals.